How to change the Network name of a MacBook?
I am on MacOS 15.1, and want to change the name my MacBook broadcasts to the network. My MacBooks name is MyNames-Macbook-`pro in Settings > General > About > Name and the same in General > Sharing > Local hostname with the additional .local. I want this (or something similar) to be the network name, i.e. if I try to arp -a from another device I get mac (I-address) ..., more importantly, the file sharing name under smb://mac. Both of these are listed as "mac" and doesn't seems to change when I change the name anywhere. At one point it changed to my ip address when I restarted the router, but it returned to "mac" on a system reboot.
I saw someone suggest to change the wifi WINS NetBIOS name, which was "MAC", so I changed this to the same name as my computer name which did not solve my issue. Additionally someone suggested changing the name in About, and waiting for a DNS refresh, can this be forced on my router, or just via a router restart?
I was able to achieve this result on my old MacBook by changing the name, and while it didn't change immediately but after a few days, the original name was the same name as the device name. So hopefully it will work itself out and I can just close this off for the next person looking, but in the meantime does anyone know a better fix for this.

I eventually figured this out, MacOS introduced Private Wifi Addresses in Sequoia (15), which spoofs your MAC address and pc name. This is actually quite a nice feature and when on any network where there might be malicious actors or just avoiding tracking your specific pc can't be easily tracked long term.
Turning this off in Settings > Network > Wifi / Ethernet > "Your Network" > Private Wifi Address, will return this to the old behaviour. Obviously you should only do this on a network you control or trust and really only if you have to.
